# Compiled C files getting no access error

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I'm running the MinGW compiler (gcc port for windows). After messing around with the paths I got it running and compiled a program. Now the executable won't open. If i run it from the command line i get access denied. If i run it from windows explorer i get the same thing but in a popup. Avg is also giving me trojan reports about my own program.

Comment: What did you have to do to the paths? The Windows path or something else?

Comment: Can you please post the compile line so that we can point out any obvious misses. And what is the error reported by AVG?

Comment: AVG gives me a trojan horse warning for my own hello world program. Here's the code:

int main()
{
 printf("Hello World!\n");
 return 0;
}

Comment: How do you format code in a comment?

Comment: @TheHoplessNoob You wouldn't, just edit your answer. You can get monospaced fonts by surrounding text with backticks: \`mono\` - `mono`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of what might be happening with your anti-virus, but I have heard from fellow programmers that antivirus can be very annoying giving false-positives these days. Anyway, check that the program that you generated is indeed giving some sort of "Access denied" error instead of "Access violation". The most likely cause is that your program can not access certain dll's that it needs to run, like  libgcc_sj.dll (not really sure about the name), or even some msvcrt??.dll . The easiest way to check for the list of dll's that your program depends upon is with an utility distributed in the Window's SDK called "depends.exe".

Good luck!